# Help writing the following query to relational algebra

Tags: relational-theory, rdbms

Can someone help me in writing the following query to relational algebra, I am studying DBMS and  I am stuck on this exercise.

Query:

```
SELECT a.name, d.name. d.grade
FROM student a, enrolled i, class d
WHERE a.id= i.student_id
AND i.disc_id = d.id
```

Thanks

Comment: [What is the policy here on homework?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18242/266284) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [ask] [Help] [mre]

Comment: There are many relational algebras. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Define "write in"--Same result? Same structure? Nested algebra calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. But--Google 'run relational algebra online'. Please show what parts you are able to do.

Answer (score 1):

This line represents a cartesian product of 3 tables:

```
FROM student a, enrolled i, class d
```

After creating a cartesian product you filter out rows that match the predicate.

```
WHERE a.id= i.student_id
AND i.disc_id = d.id
```

If you look closer at this query it is equivalent to:

```
  SELECT a.name, d.name. d.grade
    FROM student a
      JOIN enrolled i ON a.id= i.student_id
      JOIN class d ON i.disc_id = d.id
```

Maybe you should analyze the second query.